# What is the true rest method to delete resource from retrieving and listing?

Tags: rest, httprequest

In our `terms of service` we said that the content that users sharing will never delete really. We just want to remove from searching, retrieving and listing. But resource should remains in our database (Exactly like what StatckOverflow) do for deleting questions (it can un-delete either).

Which Scenario is more `RESTful` to do this:

- **Scenario 1**:

  - Adding `is_delete` with `False` default to database model.
  - Sending `DELETE` request and changing model `is_deleted` field instead of real deleting. (`200` or `204` status code)
- **Scenario 2**:

  - Adding `is_delete` with `False` default to database model.
  - Sending `PATCH` request and changing model `is_deleted` field instead. (`200` or `204` again)

Comment: if users can "delete" content, can they "undelete" it too? Or can that only be done by something else?

Comment: no they can't! I just said stackoverflow as example. We just hold their resource for ourself. @codebrane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're allowing users to delete their content but not allow them to undelete it then, as far as they're concerned, the content is deleted. Storing it with a "deleted" attribute is just how you implement that deletion and is of no concern to users of the API.

That suggests the first option is suitable. Use `DELETE` and change the `is_delete` field to `true` and change search `SQL` to ignore everything that has been "deleted".

If the users could undelete, then they're not really deleting in the first place and a PATCH might be more suitable to change the `is_delete` from `false` to `true` and vice versa. They'd be `PATCH`ing the resource into a different state, which would essentially be the "invisible" state, rather than deleting it. That would leave you free to implement a real "delete" via a `DELETE` request, as above, should you wish to implement "permanently delete".

Comment: More than your great answer, thank you for last sentence about considering strategy for implement real delete in future. I think anyway I should `PATCH` and even though currently there's no `un-delete` I think we will add it in future. Thanks!